# How does .append work in Python 2?

Tags: python

```
lword = (bword.lower())
word = str(lword)
spaces = []
for spaces in word:
  if spaces == ' ':
      spaces.append (' ')
  else:
      spaces.append('_')
print (spaces)
```

How would this look if it was in Python 2.7?

Comment: or how would I configure this?

Comment: Your code doesn’t make much sense. You are appending a space to the variable spaces, which is then immediately changed to the next character in word.

Comment: Change `for spaces in word:` to e.g. `for thischar in word:` and also `if spaces == ‘’:` to `if thischar == ‘ ‘:`

Comment: Also, try printing the variable word, does it look the same as you expect?

Comment: Assuming you mean vs. Python 3.x, that code would work (or... not) exactly the same in 2.x as it currently is. It's unclear what you're asking, or what that code is actually supposed to be doing. Maybe give a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in your code:

```
lword = (bword.lower())
word = str(lword)
spaces = []
for character in word: # character is the temporally variable inside the for-loop 
  if character == ' '
    spaces.append(' ')
  else:
    spaces.append('_')
print (spaces)
```

This code will give the result what you're expecting.